# В некоторых случаях дублируются кнопки запуска сниппетов

Tags: дефект, правки, сниппеты

Редактировал я тут отступы в [ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/641099/178988), как вдруг у остальных сниппетов на странице стало по два ряда кнопок. Да ещё и работают оба о_О

## Sometimes snippet buttons are duplicated

I was editing indents in [the answer](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/641099/178988), and at some moment all other snippets on the page got the second row of buttons. And buttons in both rows are working o_O

[image: Скриншот во время редактирования / Screenshot while editing]

[image: Скриншот, что оба ряда работают / Screenshot whre both rows are working]

## Всё ещё актуально / Still actual

[image: Ещё скриншот]

Comment: Не Chrome случаем? Видел дублирование кнопок при переводе страницы с языка на язык.

Comment: Практически перед Qwertiy правил тот же пост, что и Qwertiy. У меня браузер Chrome, в случае чего. Не наблюдал таких фокусов.

Comment: @alexolut, да, хром. Но это ж не баг браузера)))

Comment: @Qwertiy но если в других такого удвоения нет, то почему бы и не браузера?

Comment: @alexolut, "я написал hello world с UB и у меня совершенно случайно получился MS Word" ;)

Comment: Наблюдал такой же эффект, кажется при редактировании своего поста.

Comment: Удвоение происходит в HTML-разметке страницы вопроса, или это глюк визуализации?

Comment: @Arhad, не проверял, но очевидно же, что в разметке?

Comment: @Arhad, ещё раз увидел и проверил - естественно, разметка.

Comment: Ищите этот баг на enSO и публикуйте на их мете. Тут он никому не нужен, как некоторые говорят.